# How do I create an instance of IPortableDeviceManager?

Tags: c#, com, wpd

I'm trying to create an instance of the `IPortableDeviceManager` class with the method [`CoCreateInstance(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#4) but I cannot find the `CLSID` a.k.a `GUID` of the class.

I dived in to the Windows SDK in an attempt to find the `GUID` but the only thing I could find was the following line in the file `PortableDeviceApi.h`:

```
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_PortableDeviceManager;
```

That didn't really help me out either..

So, what am I doing wrong? Is there any way I can find out the `GUID` of `IPortableDeviceManager`? Or instantiate an instance of it?

Comment: You might consider changing the title of your post to "Creating an IPortableDeviceManager in C#" - since that's really what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Have you seen this article: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/archive/2007/11/26/creating-a-temperature-sensor-gadget-for-windows-sidebar.aspx

Called "Creating a Temperature-Sensor Gadget for Windows Sidebar with C#"... and it references this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dimeby8/archive/2006/12/05/enumerating-wpd-devices-in-c.aspx

Called "Enumerating WPD devices in C#"... which references this article (LOL):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dimeby8/archive/2006/12/05/c-and-the-wpd-api.aspx

Summarizing:

Step 1:

> To start, create a new C# Console
>   Application project. Next select the
>   "Project>Add Reference ..." menu
>   option. Click the "COM" tab in the
>   "Add Reference" dialog and make sure
>   the following items are selected and
>   then click OK:
>
> PortableDeviceApi 1.0 Type Library
>
> PortableDeviceTypes 1.0 Type Library

Step 2:

> PortableDeviceApiLib.PortableDeviceManagerClass
>   devMgr 
>           = new PortableDeviceApiLib.PortableDeviceManagerClass();